# Dataframes combining with multiple columns as one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following 2 dataframes with the same structure (Same row names and column names) but different values:

**DF1**

| date | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2005-01-01 | 5 | 10 | 15 | 20 |
| 2005-01-02 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 2005-01-03 | 5 | 10 | 15 | 20 |
| 2005-01-04 | 5 | 10 | 15 | 20 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

**DF2**

| date | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2005-01-01 | 0,1 | 0,2 | 0,3 | 0,4 |
| 2005-01-02 | 0,2 | 0,4 | 0,6 | 0,8 |
| 2005-01-03 | 0,3 | 0,6 | 0,9 | 1 |
| 2005-01-04 | 0,4 | 0,5 | 0,6 | 0,7 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

My goal is to combine them as follows:

| date | Name | DF1_value | DF2_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2005-01-01 | A | 5 | 0,1 |
| 2005-01-01 | B | 10 | 0,2 |
| 2005-01-01 | C | 15 | 0,3 |
| 2005-01-01 | D | 20 | 0,4 |
| 2005-01-02 | A | 1 | 0,2 |
| 2005-01-02 | B | 2 | 0,4 |
| 2005-01-02 | C | 3 | 0,6 |
| 2005-01-02 | D | 4 | 0,8 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I tried to use `melt()` function for each dataframe and then concatenate (`concat()`) them but it creates unnecessary rows for the column "**Name**".

Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution with [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for both `DataFrames`, then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) only by `DF2_value`:

```
df11 = df1.melt('date', var_name='Name', value_name='DF1_value')
df22 = df2.melt('date', var_name='Name', value_name='DF2_value')

df = pd.concat([df11, df22['DF2_value']], axis=1)
print (df)
          date Name  DF1_value DF2_value
0   2005-01-01    A          5       0,1
1   2005-01-02    A          1       0,2
2   2005-01-03    A          5       0,3
3   2005-01-04    A          5       0,4
4   2005-01-01    B         10       0,2
5   2005-01-02    B          2       0,4
6   2005-01-03    B         10       0,6
7   2005-01-04    B         10       0,5
8   2005-01-01    C         15       0,3
9   2005-01-02    C          3       0,6
10  2005-01-03    C         15       0,9
11  2005-01-04    C         15       0,6
12  2005-01-01    D         20       0,4
13  2005-01-02    D          4       0,8
14  2005-01-03    D         20         1
15  2005-01-04    D         20       0,7
```

Or use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `MultiIndex` and join together:

```
df = (pd.concat([df1.set_index('date').stack().rename('DF1_value'),
                df2.set_index('date').stack().rename('DF1_value')], axis=1)
        .rename_axis(['date','Name'])
        .reset_index())
print (df)
          date Name DF1_value DF1_value
0   2005-01-01    A         5       0,1
1   2005-01-01    B        10       0,2
2   2005-01-01    C        15       0,3
3   2005-01-01    D        20       0,4
4   2005-01-02    A         1       0,2
5   2005-01-02    B         2       0,4
6   2005-01-02    C         3       0,6
7   2005-01-02    D         4       0,8
8   2005-01-03    A         5       0,3
9   2005-01-03    B        10       0,6
10  2005-01-03    C        15       0,9
11  2005-01-03    D        20         1
12  2005-01-04    A         5       0,4
13  2005-01-04    B        10       0,5
14  2005-01-04    C        15       0,6
15  2005-01-04    D        20       0,7
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers. The second method with `stack()` gives the following error: `ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!`. Any idea why it could be?

Comment: @complog - It means there are duplicated `datetimes` or duplicated columns names. You can test it by `print (df1[df1['date'].duplicated(keep=False)])` or `df1.columns[df1.columns.duplicated(keep=False)]`, similar for `df2`

Comment: Thank you for the comment. One last question, what if I want to make only one column (for example only A in the column "Name")? What would you suggest for that? Thanks.

Comment: It depends. If need filter before my solution use `df1=df1[['date', 'A']].copy()` and  `df2=df2[['date', 'A']].copy()`, if need test after use `df = df[df['Name'].eq('A')]`